# Different css for different company - Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've made a website which has 1 design. There could be users with different roles. Roles are next :

- normal user
- admin of company
- worker
- ...

Each user on website has his company (in database its integer field) and i would like to make that each user with `role - admin of company` can change design of website for his company (for start colors of body, header, footer etc.). Example of that is that `company 1` has yellow design, `company 2` red etc. So far i have come up with idea to do it like this:

In table company expand table schema for additional columns (body_color-string, footer_color-string etc) and write values for each company into database.

After user is successfully logged then those values load from database in session and in my `app.blade.php` override css sections with session ones.

For example if i have div

```
<div class="test123">Something</div>
```

I would override that value in my `app.blade.php`, if session is not set then apply default color `white`.

```
<style>
    .test123 {
        background-color:{{ Session::get('body_color',"white") }}}
</style>
```

And this works, but it's kinda messy, so i would ask for some advice or improvement for later on (when i will have maybe height, width of some elements, etc)...

Am i doing it the right way, or this can be done even easier?

Comment: Just an idea. If your templates are inheriting form a base layout template. you can create custom base templates and then change between each template based on the preferences of the user. That way you avoid storing classes and that kind of things and using ifs on css tags.

Comment: With making templates i limit admin of company to change design between n created templates. With colors he has more space to customize the design.

Comment: True. Maybe you can use a solution like the @M.Max is telling you, store all the CSS in a field and then put it between style tags. Store it based on the role of the user, and then retrieve it using the same logic.

Comment: If the users do not know much CSS, you can predefine some classes and then use a jquery plugin like ColorPicker to store the preferred colors of the user, that way they only pick the colours, and don't mess with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can make smth like this:

You save all styles that user set into DB (companyId, styles)

And add to `<head>` on page

```
<style type="text/css">
   <?php echo $styles ?>
</style>
```

$styles - string with all styles for user's company from server, you can use sessions etc.

Comment: And admin of company will have to write all styles in string? Most of those users don't know css very well and this approach is only good for developers, not for end users.

Comment: No, I mean you'll have form for user, but save style for element, not one value, for example: user selects grey body color -> you save - "body {background-color:#D8D8D8}". And then load it on page.

Comment: Ok, i will try to use that approach, will see how it goes

Comment: If you'll have questions - ask in comments, i'll try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar feature, and built it like the following:

1. Create a model called StyleAttribute and its table to store attributes fillable by an admin. With columns like: id, name, default_value.
2. Create a model called Style and its table with columns, for example: id, user_id, style_attribute_id, value.
3. On the admin page, loop trough all available attributes using something like:

   StyleAttribute::all()

and create a form field for each of these.

4. Now you can store the filled values inside the Style model, corresponding to the correct user.
5. In the frontend `<head>` you can just, inside a `<style>` element, do the following:

   Style::where('user_id', $current_user_id)->get();

or use predefined relationships in Eloquent. Then the only thing you have to do is echo the attribute name and value, and you are set.

The advantage of this approach is that when you want to make one other style attribute available, you can just add it to the style_attribute table. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a stylesheet for each company when the settings are saved.

Then place this in your blade, after existing styles are loaded:

```
@if($hasCustomStylesheet){
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/{{ $customeStyleSheetName }}">
@endif
```